# Ant tool working problem

Tags: java, ant

I installed Ant1.8 using WintAnt SetUp and in the command prompt i tried to use the ant its saying

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\shakti>ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

C:\Documents and Settings\shakti>"
```

Can please anybody help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the JDK installed as well as the JRE? You'll need the JDK installed for the compiler, I believe.

At that point, change your JAVA_HOME environment variable to refer to the JDK directory instead of the JRE directory. You should be able to find `tools.jar` in the `lib` directory under JAVA_HOME.

See the [Ant installation guide](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#advanced) for more details.

EDIT: In addition to the tools.jar problem, it looks like you're trying to run ant in a directory which doesn't contain a build file. What are you trying to build?

Comment: JAVA_HOME path is for JDK only.

Comment: @sakthibalaji: What do you mean, exactly? What is your JAVA_HOME set to?

Comment: JAVA_HOME Set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18"

Comment: @sakthibalaji: Well it doesn't look like that's what it's picking it up as... are you sure it's not being overridden somewhere? If you type "set" from the command prompt, is that what it's being shown as? You may need to look through the batch file to see why it's looking in the JRE directory.

Comment: Actually i want build a jar file for my project in the location "C:\TO TEST\IBM_ServerV1_BES_1.0".What i have to do in command prompt?

Comment: @sakthibalaji: Well change to that directory before you run ant, to start with... you'll also want to specify a target. Have you read the Ant manual at all?

Comment: while im building im facing this error "C:\Documents and Settings\shakti\My Documents\Downloads\TO TEST\TO TEST\IBM_Serv
erV1_BES_1.0\nbproject\build-impl.xml:261: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK."

Comment: In the environment variable path for JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18"

Comment: @sakthibalaji: Do you mean you're seeing that when you type "set" from the command line? Is the JDK *actually* installed there? What's in c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\lib?

Comment: Inside c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\lib tool.jar is available.What i have to check inside lib folder?

Comment: @sakthibalaji: Well, from the error message you're giving it looks like it's looking in the wrong place for tools.jar then. If you type "set" from the command prompt, does *anything* refer to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6?

Comment: No i did'nt get anything like that

Comment: I do not found com.sun.tools.javac in "jdk1.6.0_18" folder

Comment: Start  a command prompt. Type set JAVA_HOME , see the output.
The try "dir %JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar"


The  JAVA_HOME  seen by ant/ant.cmd is not the same as what you think. Most likely the JAVA_HOME is set to a "JRE"  area